# Can’t preview search bar result

Tags: swift, core-data, searchbar

I am making a TableViewController with Core Data. the users can add new items to the Table View and these items are saved in Core Data.The view will display a contacts list. Everything has worked fine but I couldn't get a search bar to work. I tried a lot but noting seem to work.

I add UISearchBarDelegate and UISearchDisplayDelegate.
then add the searchBar delegate in viewDidLoad.

the code I tried

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if !searchText.isEmpty {
        var predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate()
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "item_namef contains %@", searchText)
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Items")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        do {
            serchItems = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject] as! [Items]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error)")
        }
    }
    self.tabeViewFolder.reloadData()

}
```

now it doesn't display an error when I type and press search 
but nothing shows up when I type

Comment: Did you set tableDataSource delegate ? & numberOfRows

Comment: yes ,the delegate in viewDidLoad and numberOfRows `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let sections =  controller.sections {
            let sectionInfo=sections[section]
            return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
        }
        return 0
    }`

Comment: in searchBar you set serchItems array ?

Comment: var serchItems = [Items]() , Items the ENTITIES name